# wrap a mysql query in a php function and print results

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have the following query that I ran on my database to remove some data:

```
delete subscriber, subscription from subscriber,subscription where subscription.status = 0 and subscription.snid=subscriber.snid;
```

But I now need to make the a php function that runs when I press a button called `clean`

then print out all the `subscriber` data that was deleted.

Not quitesure where to start with this.

this is my html so far:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
Clean subscribers: 
<input type="submit" name="clean" id="clean" value="Clean" />
</form>
```

Any help or advice with this is very much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is abvious you made no effort! but I will answer you anyway.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("serverUrl","login","password");
mysql_select_db("dbName", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscriber, subscription where subscription.status = 0 and subscription.snid=subscriber.snid;");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['subscriber.name']; //assuming you have a field {name} in your table
  echo "<br />";
  }
mysql_query("delete subscriber, subscription from subscriber,subscription where subscription.status = 0 and subscription.snid=subscriber.snid;");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I did make some effort and read quite a lot. Tis is all starting to make more sence to me now.

Comment: how do I do a check if `$result` is empty or not? if it is empty I wish to show a message that there is nothing to delete.

Comment: if (!$result){
    echo 'nothing';
}

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the button to submit a form to a handler page, the handler page would then run the query, and collect+print the data.

If you don't want to refresh the page (or have your users diverted into another page), you'll want to use Ajax.

That's where you start.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to select the data you're about to delete.

Then you'll need to delete it and return the selected rows.

```
$rows = array();
mysql_connect(...);
$res = mysql_query(...select query here...);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$res = mysql_query(...delete query here...);
return $rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to totally delete the subscriber. If I were you I would include a field named "deleted" or something along those lines, indicating whether or not the subscriber has been deleted. Then query according to whether or not that field is true or false.

Comment: That way, you don't have to rely on a deletion giving back the info you're looking for. *shrugs*
I find it a very safe method to not actually delete data, but only mark it as "deleted". You never know when you'll need that information again.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'll think some more about this.